# Rewrite Rules doesnt't work htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm doing some rewrite url on my htacces after the installation of my new website but I discover that old url can be visible on google. So I want to redirect these URL on the home.

This is my htaccess for the moment :

```
RedirectPermanent /test2 /
RedirectPermanent /test /
RedirectPermanent /accueil /
RedirectPermanent /decouvrir /


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^monsite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.monsite.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*index(\.[a-z0-9]+)?[^\ ]*\ HTTP/
# RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index(\.[a-z0-9]+)?$ http://www.monsite.com/$1?[R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^monsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.monsite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
# BEGIN -- Pluxml
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# Réécriture des urls
RewriteRule ^(?!feed)(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^feed\/(.*)$ feed.php?$1 [L]
# END -- Pluxml
```

At this moment just one redirection work ,    RedirectPermanent /test / but the others doesn't work and I don't know why.

It would be appreciate if we found a solution to this problem..

Thanks

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteRule ^test2$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^test$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^accueil$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^decouvrir$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^monsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.monsite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
# BEGIN -- Pluxml
Options -Multiviews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# Réécriture des urls
RewriteRule ^(?!feed)(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^feed\/(.*)$ feed.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: After trying your solution, nothing work, "test" doesn't work anymore and the others too :/

Comment: Edited my post , let me know